# record up time of a system on date basis

Tags: python, windows

I need to create a python program which reads the date and outputs the "uptime of the system" on that corresponding date.  We have event viewer to view such information but accessing it by code is a challenge. So, is there any way to access such an information from windows using coding?

Comment: How about using the subprocess module to run command-line tools such as wevtutil.exe and wmic.exe? These commands output reliable XML.

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I could make these tools to run to get the xml and could process the xml for my intended data. It's a good way. Let me try and update.